# Grouping consecutive rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Grouping the consecutive rows (CustomerPartNum, RevisionNum) in sql

Give the following sample table

```
declare @t table (CustomerPartNum varchar(10), RevisionNum varchar(10), FileName varchar(500))

insert into @t 
values ('C1', 'A', 'a.pdf'), ('C1', 'A', 'b.pfd'), ('C1', 'A', 'c.pdf'),
       ('C2', 'X', 'p.pdf'), ('C2', 'X', 'q.pfd'),
       ('C2', 'X', 'r.pdf'), ('C2', 'X', 'y.pdf'),
       ('C1', 'A', 'a.pdf'), ('C1', 'A', 'b.pfd'), ('C1', 'A', 'd.pdf')
```

Sample data:

```
CustomerPartNum   RevisionNum   FileName
---------------------------------------------------------
C1                 A            a.pdf,b.pdf,c.pdf
C2                 X            p.pdf,q.pdf,r.pdf,y.pdf
C1                 A            a.pdf,b.pdf,d.pdf
```

I want to group by consecutive rows with CustomerPartNum, RevisionNum.

You can see the table data, the CustomerPartNum 'C1' is inserted three times. i want to group these three one section records with CustomerPartNum,RevisionNum and Filename column data with comma split.

After 'C1', the 'C2' inserted, again i want to group the records with CustomerPartNum,RevisionNum and Filename column data with comma split.

Again 'C1' is inserted, these section should come as different row, as shown in output.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e.`MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Which RDMS are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a groups and islands problem.  However, you need a column that specifies ordering for the rows.  SQL tables present *unordered* sets and ordering is only provided by data values.

Although `filename` would seem to have an ordering, I think you should introduce one explicitly:

```
declare @t table (
    id int identity(1, 1),
    CustomerPartNum VARCHAR(10),
    RevisionNum VARCHAR(10),
    FileName varchar(500)
);

insert into @t (CustomerPartNum, RevisionNum, FileName)
    values ('C1', 'A', 'a.pdf'), . . .;
```

Then to assign the groupings:

```
  select t.*,
         (row_number() over (order by id) -
          row_number() over (partition by customerpartnum order by id)
         ) as grp
  from t
 )
```

And then in the most recent versions of SQL Server, you can use `string_agg()`:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by id) -
              row_number() over (partition by customerpartnum, RevisionNum order by id)
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
select customerpartnum, RevisionNum,
       string_agg(filename) as filenames
from t
group by customerpartnum, RevisionNum, grp;
```

In older versions, you can replace the `string_agg()` with the appropriate XML expression.

Comment: facing the error like 'The function 'row_number' must have an OVER clause.'

Comment: @Saikiran . . . The error you get should be "must have an ORDER BY clause".

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks like you are using `SQL Server` so, i would do :

```
WITH CTE AS(
     SELECT t.*,
            pk - 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerPartNum, RevisionNum ORDER BY pk) AS Grp
     FROM @t AS t
)

SELECT DISTINCT CustomerPartNum, RevisionNum , STUFF(FileNames, 1, 1, '') AS FileNames
FROM CTE t CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT ', '+FileName 
      FROM CTE 
      WHERE t.CustomerPartNum = CustomerPartNum AND t.RevisionNum = RevisionNum AND t.Grp = Grp
      FOR XML PATH('')
     ) TT (FileNames);
```

`pk` assumes identity column that specify column ordering.

Comment: Not getting the required output using the query.